# Active Reports 6 PdfExport.Export() method throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException after Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: windows-10, activereports

## Problem

I have some code that uses Active Reports 6's  `PdfExport` class to generate a PDF report. I'm running this code on a Windows 10 machine. After the Creators update, the code started throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

The code worked fine when it was run on Windows Server, just not on my Windows 10 machine.

Also, I tried switching to the `XlsExport` class, and the report worked fine.

## Code

```
public static void ExportPDF(ActiveReport report, Stream stream)
{

        try
        {
            report.Run();
            using (PdfExport pdf = new PdfExport())
            {
                // exception occurs here
                pdf.Export(report.Document, stream);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

}
```

## Error details

**ArgumentOutOfRangeException**

**Message**

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

**Stacktrace**

```
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at #mqc.#Vqc.#RZc(Int32 fontIndex, String fontName, FontStyle fontStyle, Single sizeInPoints, Boolean vertical)
   at DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.PdfExport.#7pk(Document document, Stream stream, String pageRange)
   at DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.PdfExport.Export(Document document, Stream stream, String pageRange)
   at DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.PdfExport.Export(Document document, Stream stream)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this post on the Active Reports support forum](https://www.grapecity.com/forums/activereports/active-reports-10167260-an), and some some trial and error, I discovered a fix.

## Solution

Open up the report designer file code behind. In my case, it was in the file `SomeReport.rpx.vb`.

Locate the designer generated code region:

```
#Region "ActiveReports Designer generated code"
    Public WithEvents Detail1 As DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Detail
    Friend WithEvents ReportHeader1 As DataDynamics.ActiveReports.ReportHeader
    Friend WithEvents ReportFooter1 As DataDynamics.ActiveReports.ReportFooter
    ....
```

### 1. Style declarations require `font-family`

Inside that region of code, look for instances of `Style` properties:

`Me.Label2.Style = "font-family: Arial; color: Black; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; ddo-char-set: 1"`

You need to make sure every `Style` property includes a `font-family`. Go through your code and fix any that are missing.

### 2. StyleSheet declarations also require `font-family`

Also look for instances of code like this, and make sure they also have a `font-family` defined.

```
Me.StyleSheet.Add(New DDCssLib.StyleSheetRule("font-family: Times New Roman; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16pt; font-size-adjust: inherit; font-stretch: inherit", "Heading1"))
```

### 3. Look out for `font-family: inherit`

You need to explicitly define the `font-family`, if you see `font-family: inherit` anywhere in the designed code, replace it with a font name.

## Conclusion

Once you've added all the missing `font-family` , your report should work.